# Rails 4 Asset Pipeline not combining or minifying assets

Tags: asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4

I started playing with Rails4 and I can't get the asset pipeline to work correctly. My site is loading fine in my staging environment, except that none of my css or js is being combined or minified as in Rails 3. Is there something that changed between versions?

Here is my staging.rb environment file:

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.version = '1.0'
  config.log_level = :info
  config.cache_store = :dalli_store
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by an issue on my side. Somehow I set my environment variables on my server to 'development', so it was never running this staging file...

Regarding @frandroid's answer, you don't want to set

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

as it will lazily compile the assets in production. You should make sure that they are fully compiled during the pushing of the files to the server, or before hand, to ensure greatest performance.

Here's my final staging.rb file:

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.version = '1.0'
  config.log_level = :info
  config.cache_store = :dalli_store, ENV["MEMCACHIER_SERVERS"].split(","),
                    {:username => ENV["MEMCACHIER_USERNAME"],
                     :password => ENV["MEMCACHIER_PASSWORD"]}
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
end
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. The only way I can get my images from the asset pipeline to display is to change the `config.assets.compile = true`. It's really strange. If I start a new vanilla app and add an image to `/assets/images/image.png`, I can only view it in production when this variable is set. Otherwise, even with a precompiled assets, it would not display. Any thoughts?

Comment: @kobaltz : I think you need to use for scss `image_url('image.jpg') ` without addeing `/assets/images/`. Only and only image name in images folder . If there is a folder in image then `image_url('new/image.jpg')` and for view pages only `image_tag` that will help with `config.assets.compile = false`